# Code malfunctions in Processing at higher frameRates

Tags: java, processing

I am writing a processing code for a minesweeper solver bot. When running the solver at lower framerates, the code runs perfectly fine, however, at higher framerates, it fails. I have been running the same test with the exact same settings and seed values but this error still stays. How do I fix this?

**How it works**:
Here is the gist of how the program works (Refer to the control diagram):

```
- Minesweeper gameBoard created with 'n' bombs placed randomly on a square grid.
- All cells are initially hidden.
- The solver bot has a private grid of the same size called knowledge.
- Bot uses the following values to describe a cell: UNKNOWN: -2, BOMB: -1, SAFE: 0
- If the bot does not find any suitable cell to play, it left clicks a random hidden cell.
```

[image: Control Flow for the solver]

**Problem**:
The two attached gifs show the program working for the same grid positions but at two different speeds. The one that fails is at an uncapped fps while the other is capped. (The view in both is the knowledge view; What the bot "sees" / infers)

Slow Run, Fast Run (failed):

[image: Slow Run]
[image: Fast Run]

I do not understand why there is such a difference because of the speed of the program. As far as I know, this should be a problem for lack of synchronization but I am not doing any multi-threading in this so I don't understand why this is happening.

Thanks for you time.

Edit: GitHub link: https://github.com/Buggermenot/Minesweeper-Bot

Comment: Isn't Processing built on java? I just thought that maybe there is a similar problem in Java too and so added the tag.

Comment: I do not know what it is implemented in. It uses the Java Virtual Machine, but the question is not about the Java Programing Language (unless you want to change the implementation of Processing itself [assuming it is implemented in Java])

Comment: Processing IDE is Processing java library + just a little syntactic sugar on top.

Comment: I would like to try to reproduce the issue, can I get the code?

Comment: @user16320675 anyone proficient in Processing knows it uses Java and runs on the JVM. Questions that might be related to the underlying Java or JVM behaviour are perfectly fine to tag with both Processing and Java.

Comment: @user16320675 some Processing questions have their real issue in their java heritage. A java programmer may help a Processing programmer without being a Processing specialist. Tagging java makes sense especially when the issue is weird like this one.

Comment: @laancelot I have updated the question to have the github link for the code. Do let me know if you find anything.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. What speeds are you using (I'm guessing that you are modifying this line: `if (frameCount % 5 == 0) {`, but with which values?)?

Comment: @laancelot please refer to the README file in the repo. Scroll to the end, I have documented how I was able to recreate the error. I'll write the gist here regardless, the value '5' is the factor by which framerate is reduced. Error occurs when you write ``` frameCount % 1 == 0 ``` which means the program is running at an uncapped fps. You can compare this setup with the original by setting value to 5 and you'll see the difference. Again refer to the README file in the [repo](https://github.com/Buggermenot/Minesweeper-Bot)